# Params[] call coming back nil in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scaffolded view *comments/new* that lets the user input :body and :lunch_id. When the form opens the URL string is:

http://localhost:3000/comments/new?lunch_id=1

I am trying to update_attribute lunch_id by reading the url string with the comments_controller create method below:

```
def create
  lunch_id = params[:lunch_id]
  @commenttest = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @commenttest.update_attribute(:lunch_id, lunch_id)
  @commenttest.save
end
```

The problem is the params[:lunch_id] always returns a nill. Why won't it read into the URL string?

I've been at it for hours, so any ideas will help

Edit:

Below is the rake routes from a recreated environment in a hello world app. This only has a few pages but the params[:lunch_id] is still nil:

```
Prefix      Verb    URI Pattern                     Controller#Act

> comments      GET     /comments(.:format)             comments#index
>               POST    /comments(.:format)             comments#creat
> new_comment   GET     /comments/new(.:format)         comments#new
> edit_comment  GET     /comments/:id/edit(.:format)    comments#edit
> comment       GET     /comments/:id(.:format)         comments#show
>               PATCH   /comments/:id(.:format)         comments#updat
>               PUT     /comments/:id(.:format)         comments#updat
>               DELETE  /comments/:id(.:format)         comments#destr
> say_hello     GET     /say/hello(.:format)            say#hello
> say_goodbye   GET     /say/goodbye(.:format)          say#goodbye
```

Comment: Please post output of `rake routes | grep comments`

Comment: The url you are using is for the `new` action but you show the `create` action. The params will not get transferred between the 2 methods. In the `new` form, you should have a `hidden_field` with the value of the `lunch_id`

Comment: So, the create method is to create the comment with a lunch_id that is passed in the url of the new.html.erb view. Are you saying that params[lunch_id] in the create method can't see the url of the new.html.erb?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could share your `/config/routes.rb` file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a form in `new.html.erb` and, when you click submit, it posts the info and calls your `create` action, and that's when your `params[:lunch_id]` is `nil`.

The reason this is happening is because the `params` hash does not have permanency when you move through actions. Web servers execute one single action basically from scratch every time you make a request from your browser. When you visit `/comments/new?lunch_id=1`, you are making a `GET` request, which is mapped to your `CommentsController`'s `new` action. However, when you submit the form, you are making a `POST` request to the `/comments` path, therefore calling `CommentsController`'s `create` action. But **this is a new request**, with a whole new `params` hash, generated from the new request's path **and the data submitted by the form**.

So, the simple way to fix your problem is to add a new field to keep track of your param:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :lunch_id, params[:lunch_id] %>

  . . . .

<% end %>
```

**However**, it seems like you are trying to create comments for lunches, and the right way to do it is to use nested attributes:

```
#/config/routes.rb
resources :lunches do
  resources :comments
end
```

This way, you can get the form for a new comment in `GET /lunches/1/comments/new` and point it to `POST /lunches/1/comments`, and rails will automatically set the `params[:lunch_id]` value without you having to juggle it around anymore.

Comment: Thanks Erik, the nesting looks interesting. I will try it tomorrow and submit this as the correct answer if I can get it to work.

Comment: So, I implemented the routes with no hidden field. I am still having to use the params[:lunch_id] in the controller. Are you saying there is a way to avoid that?

Comment: No. You still need to handle the `param[:lunch_id]` in the controller. You just don't need it to add a hidden field to the form to keep it alive. It now lives in the url.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by AbM the params[:lunch_id] create method cannot see the http://localhost:3000/comments/new?lunch_id=1 URL string. The new method, however, can see the URL string.

So, an instance variable should be set in the new method:

```
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @lunch_id = params[:lunch_id]
  end
```

Then, the form itself, should have a hidden field that points to this variable:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lunch_id %><br>
    <%= f.hidden_field :lunch_id, :value => @lunch_id %>
  </div>
```

When the form is submitted with the create method, the hidden field already has the proper lunch_id from the URL string.

Comment: Problem is it will put it inside `params[:comment][:lunch_id]` instead.