# params in redirect_to not working rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameter-passing

I am a newbie to rails and I am really stuck on this issue where in my control I want to redirect back to a specific id, but it is giving me a nil value for the `url(params[:budget_id])`.

I know I can get the params value as I am using it elsewhere to set the value in a view. `@budget_id = params[:budget_id]` works elsewhere.

My code is as follows, and apologies in advance:

```
def create

@budget_item = BudgetItem.new(budget_item_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @budget_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to budget_url(params[:budget_id]) }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @budget_item }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @budget_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Just a bit more info: I have a parent budgets/46 when I click on an "add item" button within the budget I now have `items/new?budget_id=46`. When I save the item I want to return back to the parent budget with id of 46, which I have gotten form the url.

Comment: Just a bit more info I have a parent budgets/46 when I click on an add item button with in the budget I now have items/new?budget_id=46 when I save the item I want to return back to the parent budget with id of 46 which I have gotten form the url

Comment: I have managed to solve it with the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453626/params-call-coming-back-nil-in-controller

Answer (score 2):

Is `url` a defined method?

Generally, you'd use the route helpers which get generated.  From the root of the project do `bundle exec rake routes`.  This will show you call the routes defined and their helpers.

Something like this

`Prefix Verb        URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
api_company        GET /api/companies(.:format) api/companies#failure`

For for the api call you can use `api_company_url(1)` for the URL, which would give `https://example.com.dev/api/companies/1`

Comment: Hi Marty thank you are right my mistake when copied the code it should be format.html { redirect_to budget_url(params[:budget_id]) }